# How to substract a day/hour/minute from joda-time DateTime in Scala?

Tags: datetime, scala, jodatime

I am trying to use joda-time with [its Scala wrapper](http://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time).

Saying `val dt` is a `DateTime` and contains a `date (zero time)`, how do I get the date of the day befor it? `dt - 1.days` doesn't work and gives

```
"type mismatch" ("found: org.scala_tools.time.Imports.DateTime, required: ?{val -:?}").
```

Scala-time examples like `2.hours + 45.minutes + 10.seconds` don't work either saying that `hours` is not a member of an `Int`.

Joda-time examples like `DateTime.dayOfWeek().addToCopy(3)` don't work either as `dayOfWeek`, for example, is not a member of `org.scala_tools.time.Imports.DateTime`.

Formatted `DateTime`input and output seem to work as meant.

**UPDATE:** Seems to be a bug of NetBeans IDE.It shows the error, while compiler compiles ok and the program works as expected with `dt - 1.days` syntax.

Comment: Note that `dayOfWeek` actually *is* a member of org.scala_tools.time.Imports.DateTime, since Imports.DateTime is just an alias for org.joda.time.DateTime. The scala-friendly methods are added in the RichDateTime class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a bug of NetBeans IDE. It shows the error, while compiler compiles ok and the program works as expected with "dt - 1.days" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the code cannot find the implicit conversions. Are you sure you import org.scala_tools.time.Imports._  in the scope that you are using it?

Comment: I have import org.scala_tools.time.Imports._ right after package declaration. DateTime type works, as I've said, from which I conclude that I've imported it ok.

Comment: Seems to be a bug of NetBeans IDE.It shows the error, while compiler compiles ok and the program works as expected with "dt - 1.days" syntax.