# Shorter and better way to find difference between timestamps

Tags: scala, datetime

I have to delete a few tests I create if the timestamp on these are older than a week.
On making a call to the API I get the created_at time stamps of all the tests in this format :
2014-08-04T04:49:28Z , 
2014-08-04T04:49:22Z ,
etc..
It looks like a DateTime object but is a String actually. So firstly is there a way to convert this to a DateTime object?

I need to compare these against the current time and date and check whether they are older than a week or not. For this I know there are several ways but I wanted to know which one is the shortest and most efficient in scala without importing any java utility. Though Joda would have been helpful but the API response gives me String
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider Scala wrappers for Joda (e.g [GitHub /nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time)
). It provides a rich API and avoids Java Date non thread-safety and mutability.

See [What's the standard way to work with dates and times in Scala? Should I use Java types or there are native Scala alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614380/3189923) for further comments/discusison and usage examples.

Comment: Yeah nice! But is there any way to change the String response to DateTime ?