# Adding Scala Concurrent Duration To a DateTime

Tags: java, scala, datetime

How do I add a `scala.concurrent.Duration` to some Java/Scala representation of time to get a time in the future/past?

I really like how scala `Duration` adds methods to integers (e.g. `10 seconds`), so I'm trying to do something of the form:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val futurePoint: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now + (10 Seconds)
```

I would prefer not use other libraries as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614380/whats-the-standard-way-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-scala-should-i-use-java), I'm trying to stick with Java/Scala language libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using an implicit class and which adds methods to `LocalDateTime`:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.{Duration => JDuration}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object M {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val futurePoint: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now + (10 seconds)
    println(futurePoint)
  }

  implicit class RichDateTime(val localDateTime: LocalDateTime) extends AnyVal {
    def +(duration: Duration): LocalDateTime = {
      localDateTime.plus(JDuration.ofMillis(duration.toMillis))
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can run the following  (warning is because of the use of infix notation):

```
scala> LocalDateTime.now + (1 minute)
res15: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2016-10-22T16:44:46.787
```