# Get time duration in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a variable that consists of date_time. Now I want to get the difference in hours for that date_time with current_time. What is the best way to achieve this in scala?

```
val create_time = "2020-08-05 10:10:10"
```

Let's assume if the current_time is as below:

```
val current_time = "2020-08-06 10:10:10"
```

Now I'm expecting the duration in hours. I'm able to achieve this using spark data frames using `to_timestamp()`, but want to see how can we do it in scala.

```
val df = Seq(("2020-08-01 12:01:19"), ("2020-08-05 12:01:19"), ("2020-08-06 16:44:55"), ("2020-08-06 16:50:59")).toDF("input_timestamp")


df.withColumn("input_timestamp", to_timestamp(col("input_timestamp")))
  .withColumn("current_timestamp", current_timestamp().as("current_timestamp"))
  .withColumn("DiffInSeconds", current_timestamp().cast(LongType) - col("input_timestamp").cast(LongType)) 
  .withColumn("DiffInHours",col("DiffInSeconds")/3600D)
  .withColumn("DiffInDays",round(col("DiffInHours")/24)).show(false)


+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
|input_timestamp    |current_timestamp      |DiffInSeconds|DiffInHours       |DiffInDays|
+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
|2020-08-01 12:01:19|2020-08-06 20:25:14.775|462235       |128.3986111111111 |5.0       |
|2020-08-05 12:01:19|2020-08-06 20:25:14.775|116635       |32.39861111111111 |1.0       |
|2020-08-06 16:44:55|2020-08-06 20:25:14.775|13219        |3.6719444444444442|0.0       |
|2020-08-06 16:50:59|2020-08-06 20:25:14.775|12855        |3.5708333333333333|0.0       |
+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala solution.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS

val start = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-05 10:10:10"
              ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
val stop  = LocalDateTime.now  //current_time

val between = HOURS.between(start, stop)
//between: Long = 32
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard way to deal with times and time differences is with [Java time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) if you are using Java 8 onwards.

Related stack overflow post:

[What's the standard way to work with dates and times in Scala? Should I use Java types or there are native Scala alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614380/whats-the-standard-way-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-scala-should-i-use-java)